# Joomla 3: How to show the parent menu item as 'active'

Tags: menu, submenu, joomla3.0

I have 3 menu positions. Each one is a sub level of the other.

If a user clicks a top level menu the clicked item is shown as active. This is good.

But if the user clicks on a sub item, it only shows the sub item as active (and not the parent item under which it comes). Here's my problem...

I want to show the parent item as active along with the selected sub item. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `current` class instead of the `active` class.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something because I don't have a class called 'current'. Please elaborate... Perhaps an example of what you mean may help me and other newbies :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and it is even the default Joomla behaviour.

It sound like your sub menu items are instances of type "Menu Item Alias", "External URL" or something equivalent, pointing to a different menu item, which probably belongs to a different (and hidden) menu.

Even browsing through your sub menus, the final target menu item is definitely not a child of your parent menu, which therefore can not be considered "active" by Joomla.

As far as I know, if you want that browsing a child menu item shown its parent as active, you have to make them actually parent and child.

Does it solve your problem?